# Alternatives to "Notes" in excel that don't degrade performance

Tags: excel

I have a reasonably sized excel file of 5k rows and ~40 columns (totals `2MB`). In my use case I need to provide some additional information to each cell, and so far I've achieved this by adding a "note" to each cell.

However, the notes make the file very big, and they make it almost unusable.

After adding the notes the excel is `~20MB` on disk.

When looking at the unzipped `.xlsx` file I can see that the contents are `~200MB` and the "comments" file is `~100MB`.

Are there any alternatives in excel that let me annotate the data without degrading performance?

PS: The comments against each cell are column specific, but a generic example might be:

```
From source system FooBar
Data as of 2022-01-19 12:43:90
------------------------------
Value imputed: False
Value derived: True
```

Options I've considered:

1. Shorter notes, eg.

```
FooBar
2022-01-19 12:43:90
False
True
```

2. Using excel comments instead of Notes
3. Using images instead of text in the notes (ie. export the annotation of each cell as a PNG and set it as the background of each note)
4. Setting up a webserver and writing some VBA to pull the "note" based on row/column id's

All of the above amount to some effort/compromise - so happy to learn of any better ideas.

Comment: What about a csv-file (saved in same folder as xlsx) that stores the notes and getting the values via VBA

Comment: That could work - I don't know much VBA, but if you think it's doable I'll give it a try.

Comment: Maybe creating an XML-file with elements like <note rowID="33" columnID="4">this is the text you want to show</note> is also an idea - especially as it is much easier to find the correct node